# Visual Studio 2012 created mdf in users/myuser instead of Projects/myproject folder. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm working through the Movies tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table)

It shows in Visual Studio that the mdf file should be created in App_Data, which when I open in Explorer, shows no files.  The mdf file on my computer is in c:/users/myprofile.  How do I get the mdf files to automatically be created in the App_Data folder under the project?

Comment: How does the connection string in your `web.config` look?

Comment: The first connection string is the default (duh), and the second is the one that the tutorial instructed me to add:

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20131125091248;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20131125091248.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection string for your context

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

You haven't specified in which directory the database should be created (the AttachDBFilename attribute). Therefore LocalDb creates it in the default location, which is your user folder. Add `|DataDirectory|\` in front of it:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

`|DataDirectory|\` will be replaced with `App_Data` for a web application.

You can delete the default connection from your `web.config` as well (unless you're using it for something else, which I doubt).

Comment: I get an error: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\myprofile\|DataDirectory|_aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139.mdf'.

Comment: Sorry! I meant the AttachDBFilename attribute, not Inital Catalog... Updated my answer, see if it makes it any better!

Comment: ok, so this is closer.  if i copy the mdf from users/myprofile to the app_data folder and use the connection string modification you gave, it works.  however, if the mdf does not already exist in that directory, it fails (saying it can't attach the file).  shouldn't it create a new mdf if one doesn't exist in app_data?

Comment: The problem is that the database name (aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139) already exists in LocalDb, so if you delete the files the database gets corrupt. If you have SQL Management Studio installed, you can connect to your LocalDb instance (the name is: **(localdb)\v11.0**) and remove it. Otherwise, just give it a new name, like `<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyMovieDb;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyMovieDb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`.